# What did Administrator (Quinella) said in silence in SAO Alicization final episode?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the moment where Quinella lifted up to above (In my knowledge, she going to the "Real World"), there is a scene where she said something in her mouth, but it total silent,

So what did she said at that moment?

**Additional Uncertainty of mine:**

- After that, the clown jump right to her, did both of them died?